# Can I access the in-game console in Fallout 4 on PS4?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

Is there any way to access the in-game console in *Fallout 4* on PS4 to type custom commands? If yes, how can I access it?

What I checked tried to find so far:

- http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72810880: answer is just "no", no source, no nothing
- [This guy on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCLe_bBoyps) says he read it's not possible, but again no link to the original source.

Various other fan forums speak about it, but no one actually provide any source for this.

Comment: Wow, people are sensitive... Same question for another game, several upvotes, no downvotes. Fallout 4? 1 upvote, 3 downvotes. All I'm saying regarding the source is that the source is weak (some guy said something anonymously and therefore it's true). I'm not saying the answers are incorrect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, the command console isn't available on console versions of the game.**

From the [wiki page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands) (emphasis mine):

> The console is a debugging tool in the PC version of Fallout 4. It is useful for altering content while in-game, but may be used to cheat as well. **It cannot be used in the console versions** or in Survival mode.

A former employee of Bethesda Softworks has also confirmed this fact in the comments section of this question.

Comment: Thanks, but some actual source would be better than a wiki page everyone can edit. How can I be sure that [what IP 69.58.51.3 wrote](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands?diff=2438529&oldid=2437165) is correct?

Comment: Well ok, I'm only suggesting one source. Perhaps you could do a bit of your own research if mine is so unsatisfactory... Or wait for another answer...

Comment: Wait, isn't the spirit of this site to make research first and ask questions only when you found none credible? Well, I did research and never found any actual source other than "I couldn't in previous games, I surely can't now".

Comment: Alright, fair enough. I'm just providing the information I found. Believe what sources you want, downvote my answer if you think it's bad.

Comment: Not gonna downvote. Downvote is for bad answer. Yours is not. It reflects what I read on numerous forums. It's good to have the advice of the many in one answer.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire As someone [who used to work at Bethsoft](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Sarah_Plotkin), I can confirm that the release versions of their games on consoles do not allow players to access the console.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Edited to add my "seal of approval" (assuming that's what you were looking for). Granted, I only worked on FNV, Skyrim and their DLCs, but I seriously doubt things have changed since then.

Comment: @putshada yup, that's what I wanted to accept the answer, which I now did. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire And just as an additional note, when I first started using Arqade, I was an absolute stickler for people sourcing their answers from reliable places. After frequenting it for a while, I've realized that 99% of the time, these game-specific wiki pages are accurate. Mods of the wikis usually take down edits that aren't known to be fact/aren't sourced properly.  I've started using them as a primary source for answers myself in most instances. Not saying you have to follow suit, just that you're going to have a very hard time finding answers sourced solely from devs or articles.

Comment: I agree, but there's always that 1% chance that people have not found the proper way *yet*. I prefer an honest "I don't know, but so far it's no" to an absolute "no" based on nothing but hearsay. And sorry for the misspelling in the previous comment: my autocorrect was active... :s

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I completely agree with the "don't state something as fact unless you're certain" thing, for the record :)

Answer (score 6):

When asked

> You've mentioned bringing mods to console, but are there any plans  whatsoever to bring console to console?  (~)

Bethesda representative [Pete Hines said](https://twitter.com/DCDeacon/status/667719936907870208)

> nope. use of the console is not supported or recommended on PC. that kind of thing isn't permitted on consoles anyway

I found this rather obscurely, but it's a better source than what was provided earlier.